# Using AudioTrack to play PCm data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am getting a stream of decoded PCm byte[]. Then I start the AudioTrack object, and inside the while loop (that works until the stream has data), I read that data and send it to AudioTrack via the write() function. The problem is, that I get part of the music playing, then it plays for couple of seconds, and then all you can hear is noise and this continious. I did try to increase the buffer size, but nothing helps. And every now and then I get this error:

```
12-30 17:57:44.012 D/dalvikvm( 9195): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 15% free 10178K/11847K, paused 14ms+3ms, total 49ms
```

This is my code:

```
public void Read()
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int _bufferSize;
        AudioTrack _output;

        _bufferSize = AudioTrack.GetMinBufferSize(44100, ChannelOut.Stereo, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit);
        _output = new AudioTrack(Android.Media.Stream.Music, 44100, ChannelOut.Stereo, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit,

       _bufferSize, AudioTrackMode.Stream);
       _output.Play();

       byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[8000];

       while (mmInStream.CanRead)
       {
           try
           {
               mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
               _output.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
           }
           catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
           {
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
           }
       }
       _output.Stop();
   }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

How would I fix this code so it plays without interuptions?

---

Do to some attention, I will edit the question.
Actually, I have already figured that out, I now get a constant sound out of the AudioTrack, the problem now is, I sometimes get a short stutter, than it continious playing. The stutter however causes a delay, that causes device to not play music synchronimus with other devices. This is my updated code:

```
    public void Read()
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int _bufferSize;
            AudioTrack _output;

            _output = new AudioTrack(Android.Media.Stream.Music, 44100, ChannelOut.Stereo, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit,
                10000, AudioTrackMode.Stream);
            _output.Play();

            byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1000];

            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                        _output.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
                    }
                }
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: Could do test with the original PCm byte[] instead of the decoded PCm byte[]? Does this have the same issue?

Comment: Couses same issue, but plays even less song.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Actually if I use my phone Samsung Galaxy A5 2016 the app is playing fine, but on my test phone Samsung S4 mini (very old) the phone plays poorly.

Comment: It may cause by the version, I suggest to use the latest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Buffer Overflow happening in your code.

Submit the buffer at regular interval based on the buffer size and sampling rate.

Introduce some Sleep in your while loop

```
   /* First Buffer */
   if(mmInStream.CanRead)
   {
       try
       {
           mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);            
           _output.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
       }
       catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
       }

   }

  while (mmInStream.CanRead)
   {
       try
       {
           mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);

           Sleep(x) --- calculate the x millisecond/second based on the buffer size & sampling frequency.

           _output.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
       }
       catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
       }

   }
```

For proper audio quality playback, check the buffer supported and submit the buffer to the [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack).

Check more example w.r.t to the AudioTrack usage.

Comment: Actually, there is another problem, I am currently having, see the updated question.

Comment: Updated my response , make sure the thread that is submitting the buffer is scheduled at proper interval.

Comment: Since mmInStread blocks untill read, and so does _output, isn't the problem more that it doesn't read fast enought?

Comment: You are reading from the static file, so you can read and keep the data ready and then go for sleep . once you wake up you can submit the buffer.